# Doxygen UML is not properly display (version 1.9.5)

Tags: doxygen

[image: WeirdUML]

Hello,
I have a issue with UML_LOOK in doxygen.

Is anybody having same issue with UML_LOOk on 1.9.5
I have tried to find why is this working weird but have no idea...

my configuration setting is

```
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
DOT_UML_DETAILS        = NO
DOT_WRAP_THRESHOLD     = 17
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 1
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = "C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin"
```

I couldn't find "CLASS_DIAGRAM=YES"..
there are no option in "Expert-->Dot" section

Class members are correctly display in UML.

Find solution to fix this issue with changing config.

Comment: The "weird" looking is a bug in the doxygen version 1.9.5 and has been fixed in the current master (1.9.6 (c2e04832d7cd54d1bc8e8484a58eeeb15b5c0918)) of doxygen (see also https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9717)

Comment: `CLASS_DIAGRAM` has been made obsolete in version 1.9.3 (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html) and has been replaced by `CLASS`GRAPH`. REegarding the "weird" attribute trz adding `shape="record"` to the setting `DOT_NODE_ATTR`.